# SQL query to insert a table based on the sort and duplicating the same for other categories

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a master table

| Type | Slot Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0700 |
| A | 0730 |
| B | 0600 |
| B | 0630 |

I want the final table which has all the slots of all types in ascending order

| Type | Slot Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0600 |
| A | 0630 |
| A | 0700 |
| A | 0730 |
| B | 0600 |
| B | 0630 |
| B | 0700 |
| B | 0730 |

I am using oracle SQL developer. Can you please help me in finding what type of procedure will help me in forming this new table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use a cross join approach with exists logic:

```sql
INSERT INTO master (Type, SlotTime)
SELECT t1.Type, t2.SlotTime
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM master) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT SlotTime FROM master) t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM master m
    WHERE m.Type = t1.Type AND m.SlotTime = t2.SlotTime
);
```

The cross join used above generates all possible combinations of types and slot times.  We then use exists logic to not insert any tuple already existing in your table.